# Multer Create Only 1 folder for all uploaded files?

Tags: node.js, multer

I have a form that can send multiple files and these files send to the server but I want them all to be inside 1 folder but when I use this code the folders separate to each folders but I want for example if I uploaded files it automatically creates a folder and save all uploaded files inside this folder :

here is my code :

```
const {v4} = require("uuid");
const multer = require('multer');
const fs = require("fs");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({

destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    const crid = v4;
    const filePath = "lessons/"+crid+"/";
    fs.mkdirSync(filePath , {recursive: true})
    cb(null, filePath)
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const filename = Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname;
    const rep = filename.replace(/\s/g, '')
    cb(null, rep)
},

 });
```

the problem with this code if I uploaded more than 1 file it create a folder for each file

Answer (score 0):

I discovered how to solve this , here is my code :

```
const date = Date.now();

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    const nameFolder = date + "-" +req.body.name;
    const dirRep = nameFolder.replace(/\s/g, '');
    const folderPath = "lessons/"+dirRep+"/";
    fs.mkdirSync(folderPath, {recursive: true})
    cb(null, folderPath)
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const filename = Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname;
    const rep = filename.replace(/\s/g, '')
    cb(null, rep)
},

});
```